# How to Make a Batch file to Run a command according to IP address

Tags: batch-file

I am caught with a difficult problem where i have to run an instruction through cmd when the computer is a server and different command if any other computer. This can be done only through batch files. It looks like a simple if else problem but i am finding it very difficult. If any one faced this problem, please provide a solution or some helpful link. I am completely new to batch files and its syntax.

```
@echo off
set ip_address_string="IPv4 Address"
rem Uncomment the following line when using older versions of Windows without IPv6 support (by removing "rem")
rem set ip_address_string="IP Address"
echo Network Connection Test
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=:" %%f in (`ipconfig ^| findstr /c:%ip_address_string%`) do echo Your IP Address is: %%f

if (%%f == 192.XX.XX.1){
cd Desktop
}

else{
cd Downloads
}
```

Comment: Type `if /?` into a command prompt window and learn the correct syntax. And `%%f` is only available in the loop context, but your (wrong) `if` query is outside of the loop...

Comment: Little more detail regarding syntax or some link or some link. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also use round parentheses not curly braces, the else keyword has to be on the same line as the closing parens of the code block.

Comment: It is something to convert both things into string and then comparing them.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way.

```
@echo off

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`powershell -command " ((ipconfig | findstr [0-9].\.)[0]).Split()[-1] "`) do set IPVar=%%a
echo The following IP is available in a variable for use in a batch script: %IPVar%

pause
```

I like usebackq in my for loop when doing a command because it makes using quotes easier for me. If you didn't use usebackq, then you would replace the ``` symbols with apostrophes.

So we use a for loop here, open cmd and do for /? for a full explanation of how they work. But our result %%a stores the result of a powershell command to get a local IP. Then we take the result in %%a and store it into %IPVar%.